# toString() removes the zero at the right

Tags: javascript, tostring

I have a number, `2.0e-14`, and I want to convert it to string. I'm using `(2.0e-14).toString()`, and what I get is the string `2e-14`, because it's removing the zeroes at the right.

Is there any way of keep the zero at the right than to manipulating the string?

Comment: If it is a number, then `2.0e-14` is just `2e-14`. How did you get `2.0e-14`?

Comment: @xdazz Probably by typing it in as a literal.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2875281/1883647)

Comment: @ajp15243 That question doesn't have an answer that satisfies this question.

Comment: @rvighne So it also could be typed in string literal.

Comment: @xdazz Good point. Rodrigo, could you please tell us why you cannot simply type in a string literal?

Comment: (2.0e-14).toPrecision(2).toString()

Comment: @xdazz I tottaly agree with you that `2.0e-14` is just `2e-14`. My problem is that I just want to keep the input value as it is.

Comment: @ooga That should be an answer!

Comment: @ajp15243 I didn't find that one before, sorry.

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros The input value, from the html? Then it should be a string already.

Comment: @rvighne It is nonetheless a duplicate *question*, that still has value here. If it makes you feel better, I didn't flag this question, I merely pointed out the same question elsewhere.

Comment: @xdazz It's a function that I'm implementing that receives that number and returns a string with that value plus a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Number [toPrecision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) method.

```
(2.0e-14).toPrecision(2)
```

Comment: Nice soluton! I only knew toFixed before.